# How can I convert 110V AC to 20V DC that pulls around 1.5 Amps without a transformer

Tags: voltage, ac, transformer, bridge-rectifier

I have a DC fan motor that is currently being powered by voltage dropper in the form of a heating coil, and then bridge rectified. I want to separate the heating coil from the fan motor, but I'm not sure how to go about doing it. I know a transformer is one option, I'm looking for a smaller and less expensive solution.

Comment: Around 10 bucks for a wall power supply is too much?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a transformer?

Comment: IF your fan will run from 20VDC  (and to do so in your current situation it would need a rectifier or be a universal motor) then a 19V laptop power supply would operate it. Used units may be low cost or even free deepending where you are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only other option you have is a switching power supply.

There are 20V 2A units which can be as cheap as $10 (on places like ebay directly from manufacturers)

There is also the possibility of building your own, but building a switching power supply from 110V could be quite dangerous.